# Error connecting to database using PEAR

Tags: php, database, pear

I would like to use PEAR for developing a website and i have made a class to connect and disconnect from database, but it does not seems to work. I ask you where am I wrong regarding the code below?

```
class DB {

    private $mdb2;
    private $connected ;
    private $error;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->mdb2 = $mdb2;
        $this->connected = false;
        $this->error = "";
    }


    public function Connect(){

        require_once('config.php');

        $this->mdb2 = MDB2::connect("mysql://".$db_user.":".$db_pass."@".$db_host."/".$db_name."");
        $this->connected = true;
        if (PEAR::isError($this->mdb2))
        {
            //error handling
            $this->connected = false;
            die("Error connecting to the database!".$this->mdb2->getMessage());
        }
        return $this->connected;
    }

    public function getError(){
        return $this->error;
    }

    public function doquery($query)
    {
        if ($query != "" && $this->connected == true)
        {
            $result = $this->mdb2->query($query);
            if ($result->numRows() > 0 )
            {
                return $result;
            }
            else 
            {
                $this->error = "The Query returned 0 rows";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->error = "Invalid Query or DB Connection Closed";
        }

    }

    public function Disconnect(){
        if ($this->connected == true)
        {
            $this->connected = false;
            $this->mdb2->disconnect();
        }
        else 
        {
            $this->connected = false;
        }
    }
 }
```

Running this code for test:

```
 $cdb = new DB();
 $cdb->Connect();
 $data = $cdb->doquery("SELECT test FROM test");
 $aa = 0;
if ($cdb->getError() == ""){
while ( $line = $data->fetchRow())
   $aa = $line[0];
   echo $aa;
}
 else echo $cdb->getError();
 $cdb->Disconnect();
 if ($aa == 3){
 $cdb->Connect();
 $dataa = $cdb->doquery("SELECT test FROM test");

 while ( $linea = $dataa->fetchRow())
   echo $linea[0];

 $cdb->Disconnect();
 }
```

Throws me this error:

> MDB2 Error: connect failed connect: [Error message: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)] [Native code: 1045] [Native message: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: NO)] ** mysql(mysql)://:xxx@/

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not seems to work"? Thats not an error, but more an oppinion

Comment: if i call $db->Connect(); $db->Disconnect(); $db->Connect(), at second call of Connect() throws me an connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your database credentials are correct?
It is not actually saying that the connection failed, it just said that you've got no access.